# What is sync for?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sync

I purchased my phone over the Internet, but the instructions turned out to be written in Chinese. What is sync and what is it for? Should it be on or off? My phone model is CJ-THL V9 3G, running Android 4.0.3.

Comment: Are you asking about [sync](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync)?

Comment: OOPS...yes I meant sync, not sinc, sorry all!

Answer (score 1):

I assume this option came up when you activated your Google account when you turned your phone on for the first time. This option permits your phone data to synchronise with Google services, like calendar, contacts, email etc. Whether you select it is up to you, however the answer is usually yes. It provides a backup of this data on Google servers and also allows you to access it via the online google website. You can always toggle this option in the phones Settings menu.